# Batch Program Issue if-then Math

Tags: variables, batch-file, while-loop, do-loops

So there is some problem in this code, its probably just some punctuation error that I haven't noticed yet but for some reason I cant find it.

I read that this is how to do a loop with `Do` then the number of times, in this case '`%dmg%`', tell me if this wasn't true.

I do have parts that define the variables;
`set dmgt=0` `set /a wl=1000*%upts%/%epts%` and I do have all of the others set.

Using the pause command I found this is the problem;

```
if %upts%*%utroop% LEQ %epts%*%etroopt% ( goto fail
) else ( set /a dmg=%wl%*%etroop%/1000
    set /a dmgt=%dmg%+%dmgt%
do %dmg%
SET /A type=%RANDOM% * 3 / 32768 + 1
if %type% == 1 ( if %snip% GEQ 1 ( set /a dmg=%dmg%-1
        set /a snip=%snip%-1
    )
)
if %type% == 2 ( if %mgs% GEQ 1 ( set /a dmg=%dmg%-2
        set /a mgs=%mgs%-1
    )
)
if %type% == 3 ( if %rif% GEQ 1 ( set /a dmg=%dmg%-1
        set /a rif=%rif%-1
    )
)
enddo
)
```

Comment: You may find `ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION` to be the thing you're looking for. (I can't verify, running Linux today). Check this: http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html

Comment: Oh this isn't the full code at the top I have `@echo off` and the `ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION` thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`if %upts%*%utroop% LEQ %epts%*%etroopt%` does not calculate the value of each side, it strings together `the contants of upts`*`the contents of utroop` and compares that string against the RHS. You need to explicitly calculate the two values into variables using a `SET`.

Your `ELSE` clause invokes a "block statement" that is, the ENTIRE contents of the parenthesised series of statements up to the closing `)` following `enddo`. Batch parses the statement from the `IF` through to the closing parenthesis of the `ELSE` block, substitutes for any `%var%` with the PARSE-TIME value of `var` and **THEN** executes the result. Consequently, `TYPE` will appear unchanged to the logic within the block.

You'd need to invoke `delayedexpansion` mode and use `!var!` to access the RUN-TIME value of `var`. This is done with a `SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION` statement, usually inserted after the opening `@echo off` at the start of the batch (hence turning delayedexpansion and the `!var!` facility ON for the entire duration of the batch)

Actually, there's no need for an `ELSE` clause as you have it because you `GOTO` a label in the true part. This may simplify your code.

Finally, there's no `DO/ENDDO` facility in batch - or at least, not in that form. I'll presume that you intend to do the intervening code `%dmg%` times. You can achieve this by using

```
for /L %%z in (1,1,%dmg%) do (
 intervening code
)
```

where the metavariable `%%z` will be incremented from the first element in the parentheses to the last in steps of the second. `%%z` can be any letter, but is one of the very few cases in batch which **IS** case-sensitive.

Comment: It was the `Else` part that messed it up. The substituting the `if %upts%*%utroop%` part for a variable couldn't have hurt. And I didn't really think the `do`/`enddo` part would actually work.